# Currently Learning Angular 5 - Is it still viable to learn from Angular 4 & Angular 2 Tutorials?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently learning Angular and jumping in with 5. There's many tutorials and such using Angular 4 and Angular 2 and wanted to know if they would be worth watching and learning from considering there are numerous changes between 2, 4 and 5. Or, since I'm learning Angular would it be worth it considering I'd be learning Angular functionality anyway?

I just don't want to learn outdated or old techniques or ways of doing things. I'm primarily noticing there's not a lot of resources or tutorials for Angular 5 so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between angular 2 and 4. The code just got smaller and executes faster.

And for angular 5, I don't think there is much change you will notice as a beginner. The changes are in some modules

So no matter what you learn, its more about learning the way to program with angular. I would recommend angular 5.

[Difference between Angular-4 and Angular-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136012/difference-between-angular-4-and-angular-5)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't say you are learning Angular 5. You are actually learning (just) Angular.

Angular haven't been changed much since version 2. It's basically the same Angular.

By the way, Angular v6 is going to release in 3-4 months. And it's going to be the same old Angular.

[It's just Angular.](https://angular.io/presskit#brand-names)

(Just make sure to check the changelog when new versions are released, there might be breaking changes! Most of them are very minor. I have migrate an app from v4 to v5 without any code changes)

Comment: Thanks, that's great to know +1. As a beginner, it can be intimidating with all these different versions, etc. but I appreciate the clarifications

Comment: As time passes, this confusion will (eventually) resolve. Nobody is going to complain: "Angular 16 is released! Do I need to learn Angular 15?"

Answer (score 2):

I'll stop by to add a few extra pointers.

1. Try to find 4.3+ version tutorials. It has a new HttpClient API, and 4 in general has quite a bit more on the animations topic.
2. The knowlede is mostly transferable. But early, 2.x versions were the beginning, so the tutorials are also a bit unconventional. Some patterns were slightly refined and newer tutorials will be more up to date.
3. Regardless of tutorial version, you should work with Angular 5 locally. If the examples don't work, better to learn it right away and then find the proper way about it, then to learn "wrong" patterns and later have to correct yourself.
4. Go to stackblitz. When you learn about a topic, start working on a new fork immediately. That is one of the fastest way to learn to work with Angular.